# sending a message from a web app to an extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an extension which provides a number of services to any web app that requires them. I had been assuming that a web app could use chrome.runtime.sendMessage(ext-id,message), but when I try, there is no sendMessage function on chrome.runtime.

Have I misunderstood where sendMessage can be used, and is there another technique that I can use to communicate from an arbitrary web app to my extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options.

First, http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable.html is the closest to how you're thinking about it right now. You're expecting to be able to add proprietary, Chrome-specific functionality to arbitrary web pages. externally_connectable will give you a limited version of (see http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#external-webpage for an example), but only for specific web pages (e.g., *.yourdomain.com but not *.com).

Second, you can postMessage from your web page to a content script (see http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication), which can do anything a content script can. If you need chrome.* APIs at that point, you can message from the content script to your extension's page, which has access to any chrome.* APIs that it's asked for.

Finally, depending on what your "number of services" actually is, you can always executeScript another script directly into a target webpage, which is similar to forcing the webpage to include it as if it were another <script> tag. (Only similar to, not identical to, because the injection typically happens after the page has loaded.)